# Compare two dates by ignoring seconds value in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is dataframe 1.

```
index                 date  Count
4      2021-01-08 07:52:18   1
3      2021-01-08 08:53:34   10
0      2021-01-09 07:56:54   12
5      2021-01-09 09:52:17   13
1      2021-01-12 07:55:58   5
```

Here is dataframe 2

```
date                  Count
2021-01-08 07:52:00    0
2021-01-08 07:53:00    0
2021-01-08 07:54:00    0
2021-01-08 07:55:00    0
2021-01-08 07:56:00    0
...                    ...
2021-01-14 08:45:00    0
2021-01-14 08:46:00    0
2021-01-14 08:47:00    0
2021-01-14 08:48:00    0
2021-01-14 08:49:00    0

[8698 rows x 1 columns]
```

I need to place 1st dataframe **Count** values to 2nd Dataframe count.
Read values from dataframe one and search in datagrame 2. If found replace the count value.

but the problem is "`seconds`" value in 1st dataframe. Is there anyway to ignore it while comparing. (I can make logic but i need some fast way maybe built-in function in python or pandas)

Comment: You just want to compare on hours and mins values?

Comment: if you convert both to `strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M')` and match them, you should be able to get what you want. Wont you?

Comment: @MayankPorwal date, hour, minute

Comment: Floor the date in df and then compare/merge/map: `df['date'].dt.floor('T')` ? Try `df2['date'].map(dict(zip(df1['date'].dt.floor('T'),df1['Count']))).fillna(df2['Count'])`

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes it could be an option. but is not it will be memory expensive. In case i have 30 days data. it will be millions of records i guess.

Comment: If you resample df1 in minutes, it will upsample at the minimum and maximum date and time. `df1.resample('min').sum()`

Answer (score 1):

As @anky suggested, you can floor the date on df as this is a smaller dataframe. Then merge the data.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-08 07:52:18','2021-01-08 08:53:34',
                            '2021-01-09 07:56:54','2021-01-09 09:52:17',
                            '2021-01-12 07:55:58'],
                    'count':[1,10,12,13,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2021-01-08 07:52:00',periods=9000,freq='T'),
                    'count':[0]*9000})

print (df2)

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1['date_str'] = df1['date'].dt.floor('T')

df2 = df2.merge(df1[['date_str','count']],left_on='date',right_on='date_str', how='left')

df2.drop(columns=['date_str','count_x'],inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'count_y':'count'},inplace=True)
print (df2)
```

The output of this will be:

df1:

```
                 date  count            date_str
0 2021-01-08 07:52:18      1 2021-01-08 07:52:00
1 2021-01-08 08:53:34     10 2021-01-08 08:53:00
2 2021-01-09 07:56:54     12 2021-01-09 07:56:00
3 2021-01-09 09:52:17     13 2021-01-09 09:52:00
4 2021-01-12 07:55:58      5 2021-01-12 07:55:00
```

df2: after merging with df1

```
                    date  count
0    2021-01-08 07:52:00    1.0
1    2021-01-08 07:53:00    NaN
2    2021-01-08 07:54:00    NaN
3    2021-01-08 07:55:00    NaN
4    2021-01-08 07:56:00    NaN
...                  ...    ...
8995 2021-01-14 13:47:00    NaN
8996 2021-01-14 13:48:00    NaN
8997 2021-01-14 13:49:00    NaN
8998 2021-01-14 13:50:00    NaN
8999 2021-01-14 13:51:00    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run df1 with resampling in minutes, it will upsample from the minimum date and time to the maximum date and time. If you re-index it by the index of df2, you will get the desired output. I borrowed some of the code to create the data from @Joe Ferndz

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-08 07:52:18','2021-01-08 08:53:34',
                            '2021-01-09 07:56:54','2021-01-09 09:52:17',
                            '2021-01-12 07:55:58'],
                    'count':[1,10,12,13,5]})
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1 = df1.resample('min').sum()

d_range = pd.date_range('2021-01-08 07:52:00', '2021-01-14 08:49:00', freq='1min')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=d_range)

df1 = df1.reindex(df2.index, fill_value=0)
df1

    count
2021-01-08 07:52:00     1
2021-01-08 07:53:00     0
2021-01-08 07:54:00     0
2021-01-08 07:55:00     0
2021-01-08 07:56:00     0
...     ...
2021-01-14 08:45:00     0
2021-01-14 08:46:00     0
2021-01-14 08:47:00     0
2021-01-14 08:48:00     0
2021-01-14 08:49:00     0
```